# How come no Spark Job for parallelise operation?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

If do something like this:

```
val data = List.range(2, 11000000)
val distData = sparkSession.sparkContext.parallelize(data)
```

I get an answer back etc, but when I check the Spark UI, I see there is no Job for this piece of work.

WhenI do something like this...

```
// read in text file and split each document into words
val tokenized = sparkContext.textFile("README.md").flatMap(_.split(" "))

// count the occurrence of each word
val wordCounts = tokenized.map((_, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)
```

There is.

SO I am confused why sometimes it generates a Job and sometimes it doesn't?

Comment: This is the basic difference between actions and transformations. Try reading the RDD programming guide, and this difference will be highlighted in the first few paragraphs. Here's the link: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#rdd-operations

Comment: That's an answer.  By adding an Action to the 1st RDD, e.g. reduce() it kicked off the job Without that the first operation is lazy and doesn't happen because it is a transofrmation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are mainly two types of operations in Spark: action and transformation. Transformations are lazy in nature, meaning, they will only be triggered when there is an action called on it. For ex:

```
val data = spark.read.textFile("spark_test.txt").rdd
```

The above is a transformation, when you run the code, it won't actually load the `spark_test.txt` file into memory. When you call an action, it will then evaluate the transformation and complete the job

```
val res = data.collect()
```

`collect` is an action, when you now run the code, the file is loaded and then collected. For the complete list of transformations and actions available in Spark, take a look at this [doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#transformations)

Comment: Also worth adding is that "parallelize" is basically a factory method which takes a scala collection and creates an RDD.  It's not even transform action on a RDD.